# what data structure to use for a tree of functions

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

Is there a data structure in Java I should be using for this situation:
Currently, I have a flat 12000 line class with a large number of functions.
Each function simply returns a string.

```
public static String[] Account() {

  return new String [] {"The member's account number."};

}
```

The problem is the strings are actually a hierarchy. To make it easier to find and edit strings, I want to arrange them as index:fname:string tuples that sit nicely in a JSON/XML.

```
10 / Account / 'The memb...'
11
12
 12.0
 12.1
  12.1.0
  12.1.1
  12.1.2
  12.1.3
 12.2
 12.3
 12.15
13
```

But then that would be a tree of tuples, not a tree of functions. How do I retain the getter functionality?

(I tried creating a hierarchy of interfaces, which solves the hierarchy issue, but then the strings are all over the place.)

Comment: do the strings require calculation or completely constant? you could use a yaml file(will provide hierarchy) and then you can just get the value where you need it.

Comment: they're constant. I don't have control over the invocations, so the function names must be preserved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a simple `Node` class with a parent, list of children and a recursive method to create the hierarchical id:

```
public class Node() {
    private int id;
    private String data;
    private Node parent;
    private List<Node> children;

    // Constructor, getters, etc..

    public String getFullId() {
        if (parent == null) {
            return String.valueOf(id) {
        }
        return parent.getFulld() + "." + id;
    }
}
```